# .getAll(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I updated Angular to version 1.6.4.
So I had to update `.success` and `.error` to `.then`

Now I get the following error:

> TypeError: .getAll(...).then is not a function

The Problem is here in the service:

```
    function getAll(page, size) {
    return $http.get(baseUrl + '/jobprofiles?page='+page+'&size='+size, {timeout: 5000}).then(function (response) {
      data = response;
    }), (function(response) {
      alertService.setAlert({'message': 'jobmatch.server.unavailable', 'classified': 'danger', 'lives':1});
    });
  }
```

Here is the controller:

```
    if($cookies.get("authenticated")=='true'){
    //get a list of all candidateprofiles with the use of a page and a size
    candidateprofilesService.getAll($scope.page, $scope.size).then(function() {
      $scope.data = candidateprofilesService.getData()._embedded.candidateprofiles;
      candidateprofilesService.getAll($scope.page, $scope.size+10).then(function() {
        if(candidateprofilesService.getData()._embedded.candidateprofiles.length > $scope.data.length){
          $scope.moreData = true;
        }
        else {
          $scope.moreData = false;
        }
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: are you exposing getAll in your candidateprofilesService ?

Answer (score 1):

You service code should be like :

```
myApp.service('candidateprofilesService', function($http) {
     this.getAll = function (page, size) {
        // just return the promise , don't evaluate here
        return $http.get(baseUrl + '/jobprofiles?page='+page+'&size='+size, {timeout: 5000});
   }    

   this.getData = function(){
      // your getData() method body, also just return the promise.
   }
});
```

Then in your controller after injecting service,

```
 candidateprofilesService.getAll($scope.page, $scope.size).then(function(response){
      //Evaluate promise here and handle the response
    }, function(error){
         //handle error
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this,

```
function getAll(page, size) {
    return $http.get(baseUrl + '/jobprofiles?page='+page+'&size='+size, {timeout: 5000}).then(function (response) {
      return data = response;
    }, function(response) {
      alertService.setAlert({'message': 'jobmatch.server.unavailable', 'classified': 'danger', 'lives':1});
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you go through this link for your question? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http